# JPA relationship using id and object instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a following JPA entities:

```
@Entity
class User {
  Long id;

  String name;

  // other fields
}

@Entity
class Department {
  @Id
  Long id;

  String name;

  // other fields
}
```

Now I would like to create relationship between user and department. When new user is created I don't want to fetch Department and set it using:

```
user.setDepartment(department);
```

Instead I prefer to just set the department id:

```
user.setDepartmentId(departmentId);
```

and leave it for database to validate foreign key constraint.

However, at the same time it should be possible to get full department data together with user. For example I would like to execute the following spring-data query:

```
SELECT u FROM UserModel as u LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH u.department;
```

Is it possible to be achieved using:

- Spring Data 1.7.1.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.2.16.Final
- JPA 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Department department = entityManager.getReference(Department.class, departmentId);
user.setDepartment(department);
```

`getReference` won't issue select and will assume that this `departmentId` exists.

Comment: OK, is it possible to extract only the departmentId key from UserModel without doing join?

Comment: Yes, you can write user.getDepartment().getId() and it should work without joins. Be sure to annotate the `id` property with `@Access(PROPERTY)` so getId() wont trigger loading of `Department` entity.